# Inserting the link of my application on HTML

Tags: python, html, jupyterlab-lsp

I'd like to insert a link to my dashboard in HTML. I tried this in a JupyterLab notebook:

`HTML("<iframe src="http://127.0.0.1:8050/ " width="950" height="800" frame>")`

[image: JupyterLab screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue with repeatedly using `"` characters, because with that you start and end several string literals in your code. Instead you want to pass a single string as argument to `HTML()`. To achieve this, you can replace the outermost `"` characters with an alternative way to mark the beginning and end of a string literal, e.g. `'` or `"""`. This allows you to keep the inner `"` characters:

```py
HTML('<iframe src="http://127.0.0.1:8050/" width="950" height="800" frame>')
```

or

```py
HTML("""<iframe src="http://127.0.0.1:8050/" width="950" height="800" frame>""")
```